# Concatenate cells - error while running macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate cells as per below VBA script but it gives me run-time error '91' - Object variable or With Block variable not set. I guess that's smth to do with variable "x"? Can anyone help please?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim Cells As Range
Dim x As Integer

x = 2

Do While Cells(x, 1) <> ""
Cells(x, 2) = Cells(x, 2) & Cells(x, 3) & Cells(x, 4)
Cells(x, 2) = ""
x = x + 1
Loop
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Get rid of `Dim Cells As Range`.

Comment: Hi BigBen thanks you are always willing to help! That helped with error! Much appreciated! This macro should concatenate values from columns B,C,D, save them in column B and then delete the columns C & D, but it's only clears the contents starting from B2 and down the column :( do you have any idea on that?

Comment: `Cells(x, 2) = ""` - change that to `Range("C" & x & ":D" & x).ClearContents`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting comments into an answer:

- Remove `Dim Cells As Range`, which is shadowing `Cells` from the Excel Object Model and causing the RTE 91.
- Change `Cells(x, 2) = "` to `Range("C" & x & ":D" & x).ClearContents`.